# How do I set the sample rate of an audio recording within Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I set the sample rate of an audio recording within Objective C?

Comment: Is it for iphone? just to make clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *settings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
[settings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRate];
```

This should work.